# <' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' Como se podria solucionar el error?

Tags: python

Estaba intentando un  codigo en el que ingresando tres numeros, si el primero es menor a 15, se debia imprimir, pero salio error, como se puede solucionar?

```
fecha = (input())
fecha = fecha.split()
d = fecha[0]
m = fecha[1]
y = fecha[2]
if fecha[0] <15:
    print (fecha[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

El `split()` divide un string, por la cual debes de pedir un String en el input:

```
fecha = str(input()) # 'str()' para tomar ese valor como una cadena
fecha = fecha.split()

d = fecha[0]
m = fecha[1]
y = fecha[2]
```

Luego para comparar, debes de transformar ese primer elemento a `int`:

```
if int(d) < 15: # la variable 'd' ya tiene el valor del primer elemento, por lo que no se necesita poner 'fecha[0]' de nuevo
    print(d)
```

Entrada:

```
>> 12 5 10
```

Salida:

```
>> 12
```